# XAMPP - connect timed out (Cannot connect to host)

Tags: php, apache, xampp, host

I use windows 7, XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1
It is supposed to send the email from localhost to gmail.
I have tried to use Php Mailer and Stunnel;
uncommented extension=php_openssl.dll.
But it is still not working

The configuration of php.ini and sendmail.ini

[php.ini - mail function]

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com  
smtp_port = 587  
;sendmail_from =   
sendmail_path ="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

[sendmail.ini]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com  
smtp_port=587  
smtp_ssl=auto  
;default_domain=  
error_logfile=error.log  
debug_logfile=debug.log  
auth_username=********@gmail.com  
auth_password=********  
;pop3_server=  
;pop3_username=  
;pop3_password=  
force_sender=*******@gmail.com  
force_recipient=  
hostname=
```

Here is my testing PHP code that try to figure out the reasons

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("smtp.gmail.com:587", $errno, $errstr, 30);  
if (!$fp) {    
echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";   
} else {  
while (!feof($fp)) {  
echo fgets($fp, 1024);  
}  
fclose($fp);  
}
```

I got this:
Warning: stream_socket_client(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxx\xxxx.php on line 2
Get the error (connect timed out.) (10060)

I tried to use Php mailer to test.

```
require("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");  
$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication  
$mail->Username = "********@gmail.com"; // Enter your SMTP username  
$mail->Password = "********"; // SMTP password  
$webmaster_email = "******@gmail.com"; //Add reply-to email address  
$email="**********@gmail.com"; // Add recipients email address  
$name="*********"; // Add Your Recipient’s name  
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;  
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster";  
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);  
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");  
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap  
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML 
$mail->Subject = "This is your subject";  
$mail->Body = "Hi, this is your email body, etc, etc"; //HTML Body  
$mail->AltBody = "Hi, this is your email body, etc, etc"; //Plain Text Body  
if(!$mail->Send()){  
echo "Mailer Error:". $mail->ErrorInfo;  
} else {  
echo "Message has been sent";  
}
```

It returns
Mailer Error:SMTP connect() failed.
I have tried to run sendmail.exe as an administrator
and make it executed as Windows XP SP 3.
But it is still not working
Appreicated if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Ty this,

Load extension OpenSSL enabled (you can enable it by editing php.ini).

Find line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` and uncomment it by removing the semicolon (`;`) from the beginning of the line.

Restart Apache (from XAMPP Control Panel)

---

**EDIT**

I setup:

**OS**: Windows 7

**XAMPP**: xampp-win32-5.6.3-0-VC11

**PhpMailer**: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

**Folder Structure**:

[image]

**mail.php**:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("email@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

As you can see, I set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` This will display step by step (debugging mode) So you can see if you have an error.

Errors can be, a bad password or if you have Google 2-Step Verification, it will fail too. There are many other errors. It will display the error

**Result**

[image]

**Optional:** I turned Windows Firewall off just in case, but you don't have to.

If you still having an issue let me know. I will be more than happy to assist you

Comment: Lea, I have mentioned I have uncomment  ;extension=php_openssl.dll , but it is still not working... Thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: @girine my bad. I did not read that part. Btw, did you restart apache?

Comment: @girine I just updated my answer. I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thz for your help. I've same folder structure as you,turned off firewall, gmail id and password is correct, doesn't have 2-step verification. But it still displays the same error.
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A CONNECTION ATTEMPT FAILED BECAUSE THE CONNECTED PARTY DID NOT PROPERLY RESPOND AFTER A PERIOD OF TIME, OR ESTABLISHED CONNECTION FAILED BECAUSE CONNECTED HOST HAS FAILED TO RESPOND. (10060)
SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error:SMTP connect() failed.
Is this error related to the following configurations?
    max_execution_time= 900
    max_input_time=60
    memory_limit=128M

Comment: Yes, I did. And Now I have changed $mail->SMTPDebug from 2 to 3. and it gave me this error msg.
Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, t=300, opt=array ( )
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server  (10060) 
SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error:SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: My best guess is your ISP is blocking ports 465 and 587. I am kind of running out of ideas. We checked firewall, we enabled smtp in gmail, openssl is loaded. Last two things i would do if i were you, change the smtp server and other thing i might do is taking your pc to some friend house or to your job and try to run it. The first will check an issue with Gmail, and the second option, will check if it is an issue with the ISP. You can call them, most of the time, they don't even know what a port means. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and quick reply. In this condition, do you think it is possible to send the email from localhost to my own drive using mailtodisk.exe?

Comment: To be honest with you, I never work with mailtodisk.exe , so I can't answer your question :-S. Sorry.  BTW, what ISP are you using? The same code, same configuration is working for me and not for you. That is weird